# Visual Studio Code can't load projects - Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web could not be found

Tags: linux, debian, visual-studio-code, .net-core

I have a project folder in Visual Studio Code on Debian 9 with a Solution file that references two projects. When opening the folder, a banner appears saying "Some projects have trouble loading. Please review the output for more details". Viewing the output shows the following exception for the main WebAPI project:

```
[warn]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.MSBuildProjectSystem

Failed to load project file '/home/aidan/Projects/WebApiDemo/WebApiDemo/WebApiDemo.csproj'.
/home/aidan/Projects/WebApiDemo/WebApiDemo/WebApiDemo.csproj(1,1)
Microsoft.Build.Exceptions.InvalidProjectFileException: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.
```

The unit test project returns a similar `The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk' specified could not be found.`

All other answers to this type of question refer to a global.json file, which I don't have anywhere in my project - this was a new .NET Core 2 project, and not converted from an older version. Adding global.json does nothing. It was working at first, and I'm not sure what I changed to make it break. I do have the dotnet folder in my $PATH. The project file looks like this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="wwwroot\" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.All" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Since I don't see any other explicit references to the SDK or its location in my project I'm stuck - any ideas what caused this to break?

Comment: Update: Reinstalling the .NET Core 2 SDK didn't help

Comment: does the CLI work? Try: dotnet build

Comment: dotnet build *does* work, as does dotnet test. That's what's strange. I'm not sure what is missing from the solution file and the csproj files that is causing this error. If I try dotnet run from the solution folder, it asks for an explicit --project parameter, but it does run when I pass a path to the csproj file.

Comment: Update: I tried opening the same solution in Visual Studio 2017 on Windows to see if it flagged any problems in the solution or csproj files, or if it made any changes, but it did not. The solution opens, builds and runs in VS2017 just fine, although I am having problems getting the test runner to find my unit tests.

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `MSBuildSDKsPath`

```
export MSBuildSDKsPath=/opt/dotnet/sdk/2.2.105/Sdks
```